# Push notification not received after clearing the app cache & data

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have downloaded the app in the playstore and fill my account info and triggered the push notification in the backend. Push notification is received in my mobile.

Now the problem is below.

I have just cleared the app cache & data and open the app again and fill my account info and triggered the push notification in the backend. But push notification is not received in my mobile. When i check the push notification log,  i am getting this message  like [{"error":"NotRegistered"}]} . I have also checked whether the token is updating or not. It was  updating while save my account info.

Any help much appreciated. Looking for your feedback. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue accrued due to ***FCM Token*** not updated you can put the code below to get fcm token then send it to the back end server in order to be updated

```
 FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token.addOnCompleteListener {
        if(it.isComplete){
            val firebaseToken = it.result.toString()
            // update your token with backend side apis 

        }
    }
```